# Checking to see of an element has content overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check to see if an overflow exists in a div element, but I cannot get it to work. Below is my JavaScript and a link to a jsfiddle with the whole thing. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var el = $('.container_element');
if(el.scrollWidth < el.offsetWidth){
   // your element have overflow
  $("nav#sub").css("background-color","red")
}
else if (el.scrollWidth > el.offsetWidth)
{  $("nav#sub").css("background-color","grey")
  //your element don't have overflow
}
```

```css
.box
{
    height:55px;
    width:280px;
    padding:13px;
    line-height: 57px;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:no-wrap;
    border-right:1px solid white
}

.box:hover {
    background:#007FEB;
}

.container_element
{ 
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
}

.inner_container
{
    width:100%;
 
}

#lefty,#righty {
    width: 35px;
    display: none;
    height: 57px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 57px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#lefty {
    float:left;
}

#righty {
    float:right;
}

nav#sub {

 background:#4C75C6
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="sub" class="clearfix">
<div id="lefty">&lt;</div>
<div class="container_element">
    <div class="inner_container">
    <a href="#"><div class="box">One</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Two</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Three</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Four</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Fiveddddddfivefive</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Six really lreerere</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Seven really really long</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="righty">&gt;</div>
</nav>
```

[jfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/whv9pp99/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You declare a JQuery object and you are using it like a regular javascript object.
If you want to use regular javascript in your IF statements you need to declare your **el** object like this :

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("container_element")[0];
```

and your IF statements like this :

```
if(el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth){
  // your element have overflow
  $("nav#sub").css("background-color","red");
}
else {
  //your element don't have overflow
  $("nav#sub").css("background-color","grey");
}
```

But if you want to use a JQuery object, you need to declare your **el** object like this :

```
var el = $('.container_element');
```

and your IF statements like this :

```
if($(el).prop("offsetWidth") < $(el).prop("scrollWidth")){
  // your element have overflow
  $("nav#sub").css("background-color","red");
}
else {
  //your element don't have overflow
  $("nav#sub").css("background-color","grey");
}
```

Also in your IF statements, you have to test if offsetWidth < scrollWidth not scrollWidth < offsetWidth to know if your element have overflow.

Comment: You might edit the answer to explain why OP's solution was failing.  I think it wasn't working because he was making `el` a jQuery object, and then trying to use it like a regular Javascript object.  It also works by changing the IF statements to use the jQuery objects: `if($(el).prop("scrollWidth")`...

Comment: You right @TonyHinkle I'll edit my answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

1. You're trying to access native DOM API methods through the jQuery API.
2. The jQuery API is an unnecessary abstraction of the DOM API, if you can use the DOM API then there's no need for jQuery. See: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com
3. `Element.clientHeight` and `Element.clientWidth` are much more reliable than `Element.offsetHeight` and `Element.offsetWidth`.

Here's a simple example using just the DOM API, no sugar necessary.

```js
var wrps = document.querySelectorAll('.wrp');
for(var i in Object.keys(wrps)) (function(wrp, inr, ovr){
    if(wrp.scrollWidth  > wrp.clientWidth)  ovr.push('x');
    if(wrp.scrollHeight > wrp.clientHeight) ovr.push('y');
    inr.textContent = ovr.join(' and ') + 
                      ['no overflow',' overflows',' overflow'][ovr.length];
})(wrps[i], wrps[i].firstElementChild, []);
```

```css
body  { font-size:0; margin:0 }
.wrp  { width:25%;  height:38px; overflow:auto; display:inline-block; font-size:16px; text-indent:5px }
#inr1 { width:100%; height:100% } #inr2 { width:200%; height:100% }
#inr3 { width:100%; height:200% } #inr4 { width:200%; height:200% }
```

```html
<div class="wrp"><div id="inr1"></div></div>
<div class="wrp"><div id="inr2"></div></div>
<div class="wrp"><div id="inr3"></div></div>
<div class="wrp"><div id="inr4"></div></div>
```